# How to get a ripple effect on click of menu item in toolbar of android

Tags: android

**What I am trying to achieve:**

- Ripple effect(native), when a user clicks on menu item
- Currently it is not happening

**ToolBar in xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

        <com.caring2u.organizer.utils.fonts.CustomCaringTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/style_toolbar_textView" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuEventsTodayId"
          android:title="@string/menu_events_today" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuUpcomingEventsId"
          android:title="@string/menu_upcoming_events" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSignOutId"
          android:title="@string/menu_sign_out" />

</menu>
```

**In Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.screen.ActEventsToday"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="MyAppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>


<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    </style>
```

**{Edit}**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/very_light_pink</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/warm_grey</item>
        <!-- ********************** Click effect ********************** -->
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/warm_grey</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this warning when I use @color/ripple_material_dark

> The resource @color/ripple_material_dark is marked as private in
>   com.google.android.material:material less... (⌘F1)  Inspection
>   info:Private resources should not be referenced; the may not be
>   present everywhere, and even where they are they may disappear without
>   notice.

But I can see the ripple effect with my phone (Android 8.0)... try setting another color like @android:color/darker_gray instead of @color/ripple_material_dark

Comment: I tried it ... no change ... I posted the style also which i am using

Comment: Sorry... When I try to reproduce it I see the ripple effect. Do you set the menu's icon programmatically? I don't see any resource in the menu.xml file.. only the title

Comment: There are only Text in menu and no Icons  same as `whatsApp` has, I am not getting what theme combination i am using wrong

Comment: Can you upload an screenshot? I don't understand how you are displaying the menus, are they inside a TabLayout? Or as a menu items of the toolbar??? If you are trying to create a Tab navigation toolbar you should have a TabLayout like this: 
 `<TabLayout
... app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>`

Comment: I am using as `menu items of the toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

Ripple effect will see only Android API >= 21.

Comment: I am using OREO , and I can see ripple effect in other apps like `WhatsApp` in the menu